# Send files from host to any VmWare VMDK

Tags: vmware-server, ftp

Can someone inform me as to what is the best way to send files from my hard disk to any of my VmWare images.

I'm thinking FTP(FileZilla might be usefull), but I'm not sure how to do this.

EDIT: some people don't seem to understand: I have VmWare Server installed. I then want to be able to transfer files from the host OS, on which VmWare server is running, to whatever VMDK file I have running on VmWare server.

For instance, I now have Windows 7 RC running on VmWare, I want to send some files from my Vista, to the Windows 7 running on VmWare

Thusly, I am transfering individual files from my host onto my VMDK. I do not wish to create VMDK backups or copy the VMDK to another machine.

Comment: Are you trying to mount the VMDK to add the files or just looking for a convenient method of moving files over the network?

Comment: No, I just want to make it easy to move the Firefox bookmarks JSOn file to my firefox on different VMDK's.

Comment: If you're trying to sync Firefox bookmarks, why not use one of the many Firefox add-ons for doing just that or use something like Google Toolbar and it's bookmarks feature?

Comment: I'm not using Weave or any of the other because it's the principle. It's not because I can do it with the firefox bookmarks that I can suddenly do it with everything else. I want to be able to do this with every single kind of file, no matter the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin filesharing has always worked for me. Install the vmware-tools and configure vmware to enable filesharing. Granted, this does open a security hole from the virtual machine to the physical machine, so be careful.

The FileZilla server is pretty easy to install. Install, and then under settings, configure a user.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will vary wildly depending on what OS you are running and what OS the target machine is running.  This has nothing to do with virtualization.  You move files into the OS the same way you move files onto the OS of any machine.  If windows, use Windows file sharing to the admin shares.  If Linux, use SCP (WinSCP if your computer is Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.veeam.com/vmware-esxi-fastscp.html

It is a secure way to transfer your disk images. Although not as fast as FTP it is faster than SCP will normall be.

Answer (score 1):

If you run VMware workstation, you can attach the VMDK as an external harddrive.

Or, you can always use the built-in file share to exchange the files.

Or, you can simply drag and drop a file from your host desktop to the VMDK desktop.

That's all I can think of now. No need to set up FTP.

Comment: +1 for the drag & drop. Didn't know that. Still, I'm not having any succes sharing folders or putting up a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

if you have everything on the same computer you can use a iso file to transfer all the files and folders you need to the vm image

first you will need to create a iso image with all the files you want to transfer to your virtual image that is done using any of the burning programs out there like nero , power iso etc , if you don't have any of those you can use this , it's a free iso creator i use specificaly for this  [creatorhttp://www.minidvdsoft.com/isocreator/](http://www.minidvdsoft.com/isocreator/)

next thing go to your vmware image and if you have the server console go to where you se "VM" in the menu and then settings , virtual machine settings will be a new window with all you're virtual machine atributes , memory , hard disk , processor etc , the one we're interested in is the cd-rom, when you click on it there will be 3 main areas , device status ,connection, virtual device node
on connection there's 2 options with a bunch of other options for each one ,  1 use psyhical drive , 2 use iso image , click on the iso image and the select the iso image you have created on the first stage
and voila the files you wanted to move to you're image are on the "cd-rom" all you need is copy them to you're "harddisk" , just remember they will be read only
clic